# Unit Testing with PHPUnit & Doctrine2: Autoloading Failed

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, doctrine-orm, zend-test

I am getting this error

```
D:\Projects\Tickle\tests>phpunit
PHPUnit 3.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

..........ok1
Fatal error: Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader::loadClass(): Failed opening required 'D:\Projects\Tickle\Application\Models\Ap
plication\Models\User.php' (include_path='D:\Projects\Tickle\application/../library;D:\Projects\Tickle\application;D:\Pr
ojects\Tickle\library;D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear;.;c:\php\includes') in
 D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader.php on line 148
```

Notice its repetition "`D:\Projects\Tickle\Application\Models\Application\Models\User.php`" of `Application\Models`. I narrowed it down to 1 function of my unit tests with the help of some `echo` statements

```
protected function isAllowed($userId, $taskId, $privilege) {
  $user = $this->em->find('Application\Models\User', $userId);
  echo 'ok1'; // this gets printed
  $task = $this->em->find('Application\Models\Task', $taskId); // this seem to be the cause of the problem
  echo 'ok2'; // this doesn't get printed
  return $this->acl->isAllowed($user, $task, $privilege);
}
```

The full class http://pastebin.com/rJungFvP

So I tried looking of something in the Tasks class that uses User ... the only thing that might use the User class are

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="ownedTasks")
 */
protected $owner;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="assignedTasks")
 */
protected $assigned;
```

apart from that, I don't see use of any Users. full class http://pastebin.com/wDPXUPSV.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually found in the `TodoList` class ... I had something like

```
public function setProject(Application\Models\Project $project) {
  ...
}
```

when I should be using something like

```
public function setProject(Project $project) {
  $this->project = $project;
}
```

instead